# Can one hear the shape of a drum for operators?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, inverse-problems, isospectrality

M. Kac in his famous paper ["Can one hear the shape of a drum?"](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/MarkKac.pdf) asked whether one can "hear" the area of the ambient domain by looking at the spectral picture. Although he was not the first who came up with this problem, his paper had a big impact in publicizing the matter, which was proved (Gordon et al, J. Milnor etc.) to be, in general, false.

Let's pose the same question for self-adjoint compact integral operators defined on $L^2(D,dA)$ where $D$ is a bounded plane domain and $dA$ is the area measure.

More precisely: does there exist an integral operator with $L^2$ or continuous kernel so that identical spectra would lead to "similarity" of defining domain?

$\textbf{Edit 1:}$ Thanks to Ben Linowitz, there was some chronological inaccuracies, which I corrected them.

$\textbf{Edit 2:}$ The operators of interest are induced by continuous kernels that are defined everywhere.(for instance one can think of logarithmic potential for planar case, or Newtonian also Riesz  potentials for higher dimensions)

Comment: This does not seem like a very ell-defined question, unless you specify the class of operators. For instance, the classical problem is already to do with a particular (densely-defined, self-adjoint) operator, namely the Laplacian

Comment: @YemonChoi  just realized that you meant to say "well-defined" and not "ill-defined":P . At any rate, I made it more precise.

Comment: The second edit does not make sense. First you asked about the existence of a certain operator. Now you clarify that you meant to ask whether a particular operator has the property in question, but you do not really specify what operator you are thinking about. So what is the question now?

Comment: I still think the question is ill-posed, for the reason stated in the first paragraph of @MatthiasLudewig's answer. Would you be satisfied with a positive or negative answer for the logarithmic potential in the planar case? It seems difficult to answer a question where people have to guess what the parameters of the question are.

Comment: Consider the operator $L_Df(x)=\int_{D}f(y)\log\|x-y\|dA(y)$ on $L^2(D,dA)$ and  in a similar manner we can also look at $L_{\Omega}g(x)=\int_{\Omega}g(y)\log\|x-y\|dA(y)$ on $L^2(\Omega,dA)$ where $D$ and $\Omega$ are two different domains. No ambiguity whatsoever. Now we can talk about discrete spectra since such operators are self adjoint and compact

Comment: If you are interested in these very specific operators, then your question should say so.

Comment: Also I don't think that these operators are compact for general domains. E.g. for $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^2$, $L_\Omega$ is the Green's operator for the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is not compact.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig I meant bounded domains otherwise compactness in most likely out of the window. Edited it. Initially I meant to keep the matter as general as possible and that is why it caused ambiguity

Comment: You specifically said the converse in a comment below. Also you systematically ignore other comments. If you are interested in an answer and want to avoid the quesion being closed, you should edit it to contain the question you are actually asking. The way it is right now, people have to search in the comments to understand the question.

Comment: I am not ignoring comments, and so you know uprooted your answer. most of your comments are non mathematical and insulting.  you are trying  to  trivialize a good problem which is as you know equivalent to eigenvalues for Laplacian with non-local boundary condition. See for instance [Zelditch's paper](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v170-n1-p06-p.pdf)

Comment: @S.Zoalroshd I am failing to see how Matthias is being insulting, with the possible exception of "you systematically ignore other comments".  It seems to me he is honestly trying to get clear on the exact question.

Answer (score 21):

This is an extended comment.

First, the chronology in your question is a bit off. Mark Kac's famous "Can you hear the shape of a drum" paper was published in 1966, two years after [Milnor's examples](http://www.pnas.org/content/51/4/542.full.pdf) of isospectral non-isometric 16-dimensional flat tori were published. So it was already known that the isometry class is not an invariant of the Laplace spectrum in general. What Kac's paper did was popularize this question for domains in the plane. And this is what Gordon, Webb and Wolpert [proved](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1992-27-01/S0273-0979-1992-00289-6/) was impossible.

On the other hand, Wolpert had [proven](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183539860) in 1977 that in certain situations the isometry class *is* determined by the Laplace spectrum. More precisely, he showed that this holds for a generic compact Riemann surface.

In their proof, Gordon, Webb and Wolpert made use of an extension of what is now called [Sunada's Method](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.81.4733&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This method actually produces manifolds (or orbifolds) which are **strongly isospectral**, hence isospectral for any natural self-adjoint elliptic operator (for instance the Laplacian acting on $p$-forms). Sunada's method is by far the most commonly used method of constructing isospectral manifolds, so there are all sorts of examples of operators, in all sorts of settings, whose spectra do not determine isometry class.

Comment: Let me add that, as far as I know, Kac's question is still open for *smooth* domains. Milnor's examples are merely Lipschitz continuous...

Comment: Thanks for very comprehensive comment. Well still it is not clear how to implement this  machinery to eigenvalues for self-adjoint operators

Comment: Kac's paper has more historical details: ` I first heard the problem posed this way some ten years ago from Professor Bochner. Much more recently, when I mentioned it to Professor Bers, he said, almost at once: "You mean, if you had perfect pitch could you find the shape of a drum." '

Comment: @DenisChaperondeLauzières - The history of this problem is indeed very interesting. It was actually of great interest to physicists at the end of the 19th century. On page 4 of this talk, for instance, by Emily Dryden there is a quote from 1882 about whether one can deduce the shape of a bell from the sounds that it produces: http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/ed012/scripps.pdf

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Are there examples of domains which are isospectral to a disk (for Dirichlet problem with zero Cauchy data)?

Comment: @bigM: I am not aware of any. Should such a hypothetical domain be non-smooth, it would be a rather interesting object in spectral geometry.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is ill-posed, because you cannot consider the same operator on different domains (i.e. on different $L^2(\Omega)$ spaces). Hence you would have to require a certain "functoriality" or so, and I don't know if it is clear what you would exactly want here.

Still, there are cheap answers to your question. For example, you can consider $\Delta^{-s}$, which will have a kernel as regular as you like if you make $s$ large enough, and two domains are distinguishible by its spectrum if and only if they are distinguishable by the spectrum of $\Delta$.

To construct an operator that definitely distinguishes all domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can for example make the following construction. Take the indicator function of your domain $\Omega$ and consider its Fourier transform $F_{\Omega}$, which will be an entire function since $\Omega$ is compact. Let $c_\alpha$ be the coefficients of its Taylor series at zero. For any orthonormal basis $\phi_\alpha$ of $L^2(\Omega)$ (indexed by $\alpha$), the kernel
$$k(x, y) := \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^\alpha_0} c_\alpha \varphi_\alpha(x) \varphi_\alpha(y)$$
will be $L^2$ by the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem (and I think even smooth). The associated operator has the $c_\alpha$ as eigenvalues two operators constructed with this recipe will have the same eigenvalues if and only if the two domains are equal.

Comment: I did not write down the details since thought should be clear for those in the field. The integral operators, of my interested, are potentials induced by continuous kernels which are defined everywhere. For instance one can look at Newtonian potentials, $N_Df(x)=\int_{D}f(y)k(\|x-y\|)dy$ where $k(x)=\frac{1}{\|x\|}$ can be defined on any bounded domain $D$.(or for plane domains, the logarithmic potentials)

Comment: So you ask this question about very specific integral operators? How would people "in the field" know this from your post? Also, these examples are basically inverse powers of the Laplacian, so they essentially appear in my post.

Comment: $\Omega$ is not compact.(since its a domain, manifold without boundary etc.)

Comment: Then the Laplacian will usually not have discrete spectrum. Do you want the spectral measures to coincide then?

Comment: @S.Zoalroshd For those of us who are not experts in the field, what is unsatisfactory about Matthias Ludewig's answer?

Comment: @YemonChoi and Mathias Ludewig :Consider the operator $L_Df(x)=\int_{D}f(y)\log\|x-y\|dA(y)$ on $L^2(D,dA)$ and  in a similar manner we can also look at $L_{\Omega}g(x)=\int_{\Omega}g(y)\log\|x-y\|dA(y)$ on $L^2(\Omega,dA)$ where $D$ and $\Omega$ are two different domains. No ambiguity whatsoever. Now we can talk about discrete spectra since such operators are self adjoint and compact