# A $n$-gon is isospectral to a regular $n$-gon (Isospectral $\implies$ isometry ?)

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, isospectrality

If an $n$-gon $P$ is isospectral to a regular $n$-gon $Q$, what could we say about the shape of the $P$. Otherwise, what could we say about $Q$? In fact, some hints or simply some ideas would be appreciated.

**Clarification :** I talk about the spectrum of the Laplacian on the interior of the polygon, acting on the space of functions vanishing on the boundary.

Comment: Are you familiar with the examples from the 1990s (e.g. Gordon-Webb-Wolpert, Conway, others) constructed of isospectral planar polygons? If you wish to restrict to convex $n$_gons, I believe "isospectral $\Rightarrow$ isometric" is still open for convex domains in general. If $n=3$, it is known (Durso, Hillairet, Grieser-Maronna) that isospectral $\Rightarrow$ isometric.

Comment: @Neal Thanks for you answer. In fact, the problem isn't open since November 2015 (see *Theorem 4,  The Sound of Symmetry*). I'm trying to prove that problem by myself in using something simpler; that why I wanted some clues. (P.S. Yes, I know the problem of Gordon-Webb-Wolpert. It is convenient to solve that problem before launching into a such problem.)

Comment: Wasn't there a theorem that both area and perimeter are spectral invariants, whence $P \cong Q$ by the isoperimetric inequality?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Yes, area and perimeter are (derivable from) coefficients in the heat trace. (One can also get a value derived from angles, see Mazzeo-Rowlette http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0019)

Comment: A websearch for "the sound of symmetry" came up with an EP by the metalcore band Sky Eats Airplane, but also with http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.9.815 (Lu and Rowlett, Amer Math Monthly 122 (November 2015) 815-835), which, I presume, is what OP had in mind. It might have been better for all, had OP told us what he knew when he first posted the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rowlett is hosting *The Sound of Symmetry* [here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rowlett/monthly.pdf). The proof of Theorem 4 is exactly as Noam Elkies suggests: Via the Dirichlet heat trace's asymptotic expansion, both area and perimeter are determined by the spectrum, and so for any $n$-gon $\Omega$ the isoperimetric ratio $|\Omega|/|\partial\Omega|^2$ is determined by the spectrum. The content of the proof is that this ratio is globally maximized among $n$-gons at the regular $n$-gon. This determines the regular $n$-gon and implies that any $n$-gon isospectral to the regular $n$-gon is in fact isometric to it. Unless there's a point in the proof where you're confused, I think this settles the question.

(I have a suspicion that the third coefficient of the heat trace in convex polygons 
$$ \frac{1}{24}\sum_{\mbox{angles }\alpha_i} \bigg(\frac{\pi}{\alpha_i} - \frac{\alpha_i}{\pi}\bigg) $$
is also extremal at the regular $n$-gon. This may be another way to show a version of the desired result for convex $n$-gons.)

Comment: Your "suspicion" is correct, and can be proved in various standard ways (convexity, AM-HM inequality, Cauchy-Schwarz, . . .).  Note that the $\sum_i -\alpha_i/\pi$ part of the sum is constant.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thank you for the addendum. Glad my instinct is on point here -- looks like I have a nice little exercise for the train ride in the morning. :)